# SQL- Inserting a row in sql query result

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I achieve this? For example I have this query result:

```
IDNO PRICE 
001   5 
002   5 
003   5 
004   5 
005   5
```

Then I want to add to every `id` no another price like this:

```
IDNO PRICE 
001   5 
001   10 
002   5 
002   10 
003   5 
003   10 
004   5 
004   10 
005   5 
005   10
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean you want to concatenate the string?  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481218/insert-same-row-multiple-times-within-sql-table-based-on-unique-value-in-field-1

Comment: I cannot really figure out what is the rule to obtain the second result.

Comment: Table 1 is a result of combine tables..  then for the second table i just need to add that values temporarily.. i cant just do insert command

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO yourTable
SELECT idNo,10
FROM yourTable


SELECT * FROM yourTable
ORDER BY idNo
```

Answer (score 0):

One course of action would be to add another column to the table, so that you have one column named PRICE1 and one named PRICE2. That is of course assuming you'll only need those two prices.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT     IDNO, PRICE
FROM         price UNION SELECT idno,'10' FROM price
```

This could get your answer tell me if not i have not tested it